# My Toaster component is not creating multiple toasters on multiple clicks. Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have made a toaster component which is only rendering 1 toaster on 1 or multiple clicks, but I need a component the renders multiple toasters on multiple clicks.

This is my Toaster Component.

```
   import React, {Component} from 'react'
import '../stylesheets/adminlte.css'

ToastMsg = (props) => (
    <div className=" snackbar" key={props.idx}>
        <div className="card-header">
            <h3 className="card-title">Toast</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="card-body">{props.message}</div>
        <div className="card-footer"/>
    </div>
)

createtoaster = () => {
    if (this.state.show) {
        return this
            .state
            .message
            .map((msg, idx) => <ToastMsg idx={idx} message={msg}/>)
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}

render() {
return (
        <div className="col-md-2 offset-md-9">
            <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={this.handleOpen}></button>
            {this.createtoaster()}

        </div>
)
}
```

I am providing `this.state.message` from another component and passsing it via props. I cannot use any Library as per the requirement so if anyone can help me with this, It is appreciated. Also feel free to point out any mistakes in my code.

Comment: @itaza why not create different component for each message like `messages.map((message) => <MyToaster message={message} />)` and remove loop inside `MyToaster` component

Comment: The message is hard-quoted and i just want to display 1 Message in the toaster

Comment: ok got it, so problem is in this line `<div className="card-body">{this.state.message[i]}</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

missing array element 'picker': < div className="card-body">{this.state.message **[i]** }

I would use map, too ... with `key` property for each item.

Are you sure you're receiving array with more elements ?

Comment: Can you add an awnser with map method.

Comment: you can use sth like that:

`createtoaster = () => {
    if (this.state.show) {
      return this.state.message.map( (msg, idx) => (
          <div className=" snackbar" key={idx}>
            <div className="card-header">
              <h3 className="card-title">Toast</h3>
            </div>

            <div className="card-body">{msg}</div>

            <div className="card-footer" />
          </div>
        ))
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };`

Comment: still isn't giving multiple toasters.

Comment: AGAIN: Are you sure you're receiving array with more elements ?

Comment: Yes I am reciving more messages in this.state.message

Comment: `console.log(this.state.message)` or `console.log(this.state.message.length)` in render, after length condition ?

Comment: Yes I am reciving more messages in this.state.message

Comment: disable css, analyze html structure, react props in debugger - maybe you're displaying all in the same (abs) place?

Comment: React dev tools will help more if every message will be component:

`ToastMsg = (props) => ( <div className=" snackbar" key={props.idx}> <div className="card-header"> <h3 className="card-title">Toast</h3> </div> <div className="card-body">{props.message}</div> <div className="card-footer" /> </div> )`


`createtoaster = () => { if (this.state.show) { return this.state.message.map( (msg, idx) => <ToastMsg idx={idx} message={msg} /> ) } else { return null; } };`

Comment: update question with log of this.state.message & current code state

Comment: I updated the code but it is giving me compiling errors

Comment: where is the rest - your main component ? ToastMsg is additional sub-component, shuold be defined outside of main